# Python rasterio for saving GeoTIFF files and read in ArcGIS or QGIS

Tags: python, geotiff-tiff, rasterio, save, rapideye

After following the steps in the tutorial of the Planet website (https://developers.planet.com/tutorials/convert-planetscope-imagery-from-radiance-to-reflectance/), I want to save each individual band of a RapidEye image Level 3B as a separate GeoTIFF layer file to be able to open it in any other GIS-software such as QGIS, ArcGIS other. I could not succeed in saving each band separately as GeoTIFF layer file. Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8

import rasterio
import numpy as np

filename = "20180308_133037_1024_3B_AnalyticMS.tif"

# Load red and NIR bands - note all PlanetScope 4-band images have band order BGRN
with rasterio.open(filename) as src:
    band_blue_radiance = src.read(1)

with rasterio.open(filename) as src:
    band_green_radiance = src.read(2)

with rasterio.open(filename) as src:
    band_red_radiance = src.read(3)

with rasterio.open(filename) as src:
    band_nir_radiance = src.read(4)

from xml.dom import minidom

xmldoc = minidom.parse("20180308_133037_1024_3B_AnalyticMS_metadata.xml")
nodes = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("ps:bandSpecificMetadata")

# XML parser refers to bands by numbers 1-4
coeffs = {}
for node in nodes:
    bn = node.getElementsByTagName("ps:bandNumber")[0].firstChild.data
    if bn in ['1', '2', '3', '4']:
        i = int(bn)
        value = node.getElementsByTagName("ps:reflectanceCoefficient")[0].firstChild.data
        coeffs[i] = float(value)

print "Conversion coefficients:", coeffs

# Multiply the Digital Number (DN) values in each band by the TOA reflectance coefficients
band_blue_reflectance = band_blue_radiance * coeffs[1]
band_green_reflectance = band_green_radiance * coeffs[2]
band_red_reflectance = band_red_radiance * coeffs[3]
band_nir_reflectance = band_nir_radiance * coeffs[4]

import numpy as np
print "Red band radiance is from {} to {}".format(np.amin(band_red_radiance), np.amax(band_red_radiance))
print "Red band reflectance is from {} to {}".format(np.amin(band_red_reflectance), np.amax(band_red_reflectance))

print "Before Scaling, red band reflectance is from {} to {}".format(np.amin(band_red_reflectance), np.amax(band_red_reflectance))

# Here we include a fixed scaling factor. This is common practice.
scale = 10000
blue_ref_scaled = scale * band_blue_reflectance
green_ref_scaled = scale * band_green_reflectance
red_ref_scaled = scale * band_red_reflectance
nir_ref_scaled = scale * band_nir_reflectance

print "After Scaling, red band reflectance is from {} to {}".format(np.amin(red_ref_scaled), np.amax(red_ref_scaled))
```

Here I tried unsuccessfully to save each individual band as GeoTIFF file.

I have tried, any idea how to do the save of each band correctly to further open in QGIS orArGIS for calculating NDVI there?

```
dst_crs='EPSG:32720'

##  saving bands individualy  
new_dataset = rasterio.open(
       'ReflectanceB1.tif',
       'w',
       driver='GTiff',
       height=band_blue_reflectance.shape[0],
       width=band_blue_reflectance.shape[1],
       count=1,
       dtype=band_blue_reflectance.dtype,
       crs=dst_crs,
)    

new_dataset.write(band_blue_reflectance, 1)
new_dataset.close()


new_dataset = rasterio.open(
       'ReflectanceB2.tif',
       'w',
       driver='GTiff',
       height=band_red_reflectance.shape[0],
       width=band_red_reflectance.shape[1],
       count=1,
       dtype=band_red_reflectance.dtype,
       crs=dst_crs,
)    

new_dataset.write(band_red_reflectance, 1)
new_dataset.close()

new_dataset = rasterio.open(
       'ReflectanceB3.tif',
       'w',
       driver='GTiff',
       height=band_red_reflectance.shape[0],
       width=band_red_reflectance.shape[1],
       count=1,
       dtype=band_red_reflectance.dtype,
       crs=dst_crs,
)    

new_dataset.write(band_red_reflectance, 1)
new_dataset.close()    


new_dataset = rasterio.open(
       'ReflectanceB4.tif',
       'w',
       driver='GTiff',
       height=band_red_reflectance.shape[0],
       width=band_red_reflectance.shape[1],
       count=1,
       dtype=band_red_reflectance.dtype,
       crs=dst_crs,
)    

new_dataset.write(band_red_reflectance, 1)
new_dataset.close()
```

I'm using as input image "20180308_133037_1024_3B_AnalyticMS.tif" instead of "20180308_133037_1024_3B_AnalyticMS_SR.tif" don't know if is the problem

I'm getting resulting GeoTIFF file but when I open it in ArcMap I get this error

[image]

The GeoTIFF band are there and can be seen at ArcMap screen...   but the error appear anyway... might be related to coordinate systems to be defined possibly while saving in rasterio? And need to have it correctly projected for clipping with shapefiles.

I have done the change in data frame properties before loading the raster layer as

[image]

But the same worning appears

In Jupyter notebook I got the following warning...

[image]

Comment: That is not an error, but a warning. You need to report the canvas coordinate reference -- it could be the data added previously that caused the problem.

Comment: how can I do that? thakns

Comment: Vince can you give me a hint on how to do that?

Comment: Not in two of the three products you've got listed. An ArcMap canvas has Data Frame properties through a right click on the LayerList. You need to provide individual spatial reference properties for all the objects as well.  This is the core of your problem, but it's not described anywhere in the question.

Comment: Hi Vince, see above I tried to define the data frame you mention but the warning still appears.... the warning say something about the extent, may it be possible that when I use rasterio package saving function in the arguments there is some input argument not defined related to either extent, projected coordinates systems or maybe transform  .... ??

Comment: If you have to define the spatial reference of the data frame after data has been added, then your data is missing a spatial reference. You still haven't reported the spatial reference of the rasters you've created.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that you are not writing out the transform. I think that is the main problem.

Here is how you can retrieve and write the information:

```py
with rasterio.open(filename) as src:
    dst_transform = src.transform
    dst_crs = src.crs

##  saving bands individualy  
new_dataset = rasterio.open(
       'ReflectanceB1.tif',
       'w',
       driver='GTiff',
       height=band_blue_reflectance.shape[0],
       width=band_blue_reflectance.shape[1],
       count=1,
       dtype=band_blue_reflectance.dtype,
       crs=dst_crs,
       transform=dst_transform,
)
```